# File destination, source, number of rows , columns and other information while processing excel data source using Talend open studio

Tags: data-science, talend

I'm converting excel data source to json by taking all data in a file and saving it. Now I'm looking for number of records in the output file, number of input, source path of excel file, etc. look at it if somebody can guide me thanks.

[image: thanks in Advance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tFileOutputJson put a tJava component .

Flow would be

```
tFileInputExcel->main->tFileOutputJson ->onComponentOK->tJava
```

In your tJava put this code :

```
System.out.println(((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileInputExcel_1_NB_LINE"))) ;
```

**For explanation :**

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileInputExcel_1_NB_LINE")) is a global Variable that you can find in the outline of your studio
```

For othen information a `tFileProperties`  would do the staff here is the link

https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/tfileproperties/tfileproperties-standard-properties